# Running java webapp on iis

Tags: java, iis

this is my first question i am posting

PROBLEM::
        i am using helicon zoo for running java webapp on iis server(using this as reference ::[run java servlet on IIS](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/)), but i am facing some problems

i put my app directory in `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/myapp`(it includes web-inf)
then `web.config` inside it
My `web.config` looks like::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <heliconZoo>
      <application name="jetty.project" >
        <environmentVariables>
          <add name="CONTEXT_PATH" value="%APPL_VIRTUAL_PATH%" />
          <add name="WAR_EXTRACT_PATH" value="%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%" />
          <add name="WAR_FILE" value="%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </application>
    </heliconZoo>
    <handlers>
      <add name="jetty.project#x86" scriptProcessor="java.jetty"  path="*" verb="*" modules="HeliconZoo_x86" preCondition="bitness32" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
      <add name="jetty.project#x64" scriptProcessor="java.jetty"  path="*" verb="*" modules="HeliconZoo_x64" preCondition="bitness64" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and iis showing following error::

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "jetty.project#x64" has a bad module "HeliconZoo_x64" in its module list
```

can anyone help me..

oh one more thing i have visual studio installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in web.config file.
giving proper path for war file solved the issue.

and for
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "jetty.project#x64" has a bad module "HeliconZoo_x64" in its module list

this error reinstalled web installer

Answer (score 0):

try changing requiredAccess field to execute
and make sure that .war file is present there..