# Running java on IIS

Tags: java, iis, servlets

I want to run some java servlets on a web app hosted on IIS.  I see this old thread [Running java webapp on iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009583/running-java-webapp-on-iis)  covers what I am trying to do but just wondered is there any more up to date approach I should be using instead.

Comment: Right after that post, Microsoft created HTTP Platform Handler, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/manjug/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8

Comment: Do I need tomcat installed as well with that?  What I am trying to do is basically run a java servlet on IIS.  Can it be done.  I want to use a hosting service similar to this https://www.mochahost.com/webhosting.php

Comment: IIS doesn't support Java natively, so you need a Java app server (either Tomcat or another). Ask the service provider first, about how they can support your web app as well as Java servlets. Don't pay them in advance, as small providers probably don't allow you to run the two together and the charge can be expensive.

Comment: Yea,  asked them if it possible to install any dependencies like tomcat and they told me only possible to run it on their linux offering,  but we are tied to IIS/windows for other components.